# Нужно ли выделить запятыми "к примеру"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Возьмем(,) к примеру(,) учебную программу: она не подлежит пересмотру, только если не будет изменений в программе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном предложении "***к примеру***" нужно выделить запятыми.

[**К ПРИМЕРУ (СКАЗАТЬ)**, *вводное сочетание*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_367)

> *Вот, к примеру, идешь ты в бой и думаешь: «Иду я за родную землю». Так вот ты и скажи: за что же ты идешь?* К. Паустовский, Бакенщик.

"***К примеру***" бывает и просто сочетанием предлога с существительным, например:

*К примеру было предложено три варианта решения.*

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с предыдущим ответом. Но просто чтобы мы понимали всю картину, присовокуплю такую цитату из справочника вводных слов:

**"Для примера"**

> Обычно **невводное**, употребляется в функции обстоятельства образа действия, не обособляется: Возьмем **для примера** хоть научно-литературное развитие страны
> (М.Салтыков-Щедрин); Вот **для примера** некоторые идеи его
> речи (А.Зиновьев).

Дело, видимо, в том, что **к примеру** имеет более широкую область применения. Но даже когда оно стоит в позиции **для примера**, то есть синонимично с ним, как в нашем предложении, даже тогда оно не обычно для обстоятельства.
Глагольные обстоятельства у нас отвечают на вопрос (для чего?), но не отвечают на вопрос (к чему?) в переносном смысле. Ср. Дело катится к весне. Но: Что-то что-то делает к примеру. ??? К примеру было предложено три варианта решения (здесь уже опять буквальный смысл)